# в массиве array null нужно переместить в конец массива

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Defragment {
    public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if (array[index] == null) {
                int point = index;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if (array[i] != null) {
                        int notNullIndex = i;
                        i = point;
                        point = notNullIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(array[index] + " ");
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {"I", null, "wanna", null, "be", null, "compressed"};
        String[] compressed = compress(input);
        System.out.println();
        for (int index = 0; index < compressed.length; index++) {
            System.out.print(compressed[index] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Без стримов будет так:

```
public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
    String[] result = new String[array.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String value : array) {
        if (value != null) result[i++] = value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Со стримами, помимо уже указанного способа с сортировкой, можно таким способом :

```
public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
    return Stream.of(array)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toArray(v -> new String[array.length]);
}
```

Comment: ну любой стрим можно заменить циклом. :)

Comment: @Aziz Umarov понятное дело, мне стримы тоже нравятся больше))

Comment: Да конечно, я б тоже сделал циклом если не успевать ответить. Не повторять же ответ

Comment: result[i++] = value; вот это выражение что он делает? Ребята строго не судите меня, я только учусь программировать

Comment: @Rasim Zamaltdinov i++ - это инкремент. увеличивает значение i на 1. result[i++] = value - в этом случае увеличение происходит после присвоения. result[++i] = value , а если записать так, то будет происходить перед присвоением

Comment: @Aziz Umarov я вообще написал 2 решения : со стримамии без. Но раз стрим уже есть, оставил только цикл.

Comment: Да без проблем. Никаких притензий. Лишь бы это помогло человеку

Comment: @Aziz Umarov в моем решении где ошибка? Я так понимаю ошибка во втором цикле?

Comment: @RasimZamaltdinov ошибка в реализации пузырковой сортировки

Answer (score 0):

так посмотрите

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"I", null, "wanna", null, "be", null, "compressed"};

    Stream.of(input)
        .sorted((a, b) -> a == null ? 1 : -1)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

А ваш код я бы изменил так. Чтоб не копировать ответ с низу

```
public static String[] compress(String[] array) {
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length - index - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
          String notNullIndex = array[i + 1];
          array[i + 1] = array[i];
          array[i] = notNullIndex;
        }
      }

      System.out.print(array[index] + " ");
    }
    return array;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"I", null, "wanna", null, "be", null, "compressed"};
    String[] compressed = compress(input);
    System.out.println();
    for (int index = 0; index < compressed.length; index++) {
      System.out.println(compressed[index] + " ");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String [] result = new String[array.length];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != null){
            result[count] = array[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = result[i];
    }
```

**Как вариант можно просто записать все данные из одного массива в другой ,а потом залить их обратно и все отсортировано**